# Magento CMS broken - redirects incorrectly

Tags: magento

We've recently experienced issues with our website that is causing two specific issues.

1. When in the backend of our Magento website the website kicks us out and redirects us to the front end of our website.
2. Customers on the front end of the website also encounter issues and are redirected either back to the page that they have just visited or to an alternative page.

We have not had any development for some time so we are concerned as to how this issue has arisen.

The website is www.forzasupplements.co.uk

Comment: With this level of information its really hard to give you a correct solution

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?